# Confused about container network isolation with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have Docker running on a couple of Ubuntu 18.04 vms and also on a Synology DS218+. There is inconsistent behaviour between the two with regards to the ability for containers to access other hosts on the local network. I am confused as to what exactly is happening here:

My method of testing this is to launch an interactive shell with bash into a container that has ping installed. From that I can test connectivity to other containers and to the docker hosts. The containers are using default bridge networks. I understand this should mean that they can only communicate with other containers that are on the same bridge network.

On the Synology, when I bash into a container, I am not able to ping the host that the machine is running on. That seems to be desired behaviour. However, if I try to ping other machines on the host network, the container receives a response. This shouldn't happen as the default bridge network is supposed to be isolated from the host network. I tried taking down all containers, stopping the docker daemon, flushing iptables and bring everything back up again. Same result.

On the Ubuntu hosts, I can not only ping other machines on the host network, but the host that the container is running on.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: what is your final goal?

Comment: This is for my own education. I want to maintain good security practices on my home lab. I think containers should be isolated from the host network unless using host networking which is an explicit directive. Something is going wrong here.

Comment: Got you. It would be useful if you will create a reproducible example, such like docker-compose file, commands that you run and specific questions about particular command

Comment: Docker exec -it CONTAINERNAME bash. That launches a shell into the container. That requires Ping installed on the container. The behaviour is as described above.